# How to change the height of empty cells in the tableView footer?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have only one `cell` in my `tableView`. This `cell` has `fixed height`. Under this `cell` I have a lot of empty cells, that are actually not cells and are created by default. All these cell have `separator` so in is not difficult to see the height.

How to make these non cells (that are in the `tableView` footer) height different from the height of the first `cell`?

I've tried to use `heightForRowAtIndexPath`

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        return 140.0
    }
    return 70.0
}
```

but as I see it is called only for real cell, but not for `tableView` footer cells.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a real solution for this, so I've just came up with creating the `tableView.tableFooterView` that looks like cells.

```
    let unselectedCellHeight = CGFloat(70.0)
    let screenHeight = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height
    let cellsAmount = Int(round(Float(screenHeight/unselectedCellHeight)))
    let tableFooter = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: screenHeight))
    for i in 1...cellsAmount {
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: unselectedCellHeight*CGFloat(i), width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: 1))
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.cellHeaderGrayColor()
        tableFooter.addSubview(view)
    }
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = tableFooter
```